# Attaching prefab's script to another prefab as a component

Tags: unity-game-engine, prefab

I have Player prefab with script Player

Also I have GameController prefab with script TouchMove.
This is TouchMove code:

```
public class TouchMove{
    [SerializeField] Player player;
    .....
}
```

So TouchMove has player object as a component, which I attach through unity inspector.
TouchMove script is responsible for player movement. That is why it neads the player object.

Also I have a lot of scenes and each one contains GameController and Player objects.
When I modify the GameController or Player components I wanted the all game objects at the all scenes to be updated. That is why I decided to create prefabs: GameController prefab and Player prefab.

In inspector I added Player prefab to GameController prefab because TouchMove of GameController requares player object.

[image]

But after it **when I run the game the player script gets not active**. I mean that I get unable to move player in the game. (the player script gets not working)
**This problem solves if I attach Player to GameController *as just game objects* (not the prefabs or without prefabs)**

So, my questions:

1. why player scripts gets not working if I attach it with prefabs and it works if I attach just as game objects (without prefabs)
2. Is it possible to link two prefabs in the way I described?

Comment: Try having your player as an singleton and not Remaking it each scene or write something to remember all the settings and reapply them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting this problem is that player prefab and *specific instance* of the player prefab - are not the same object. They are both GameObject-s, and can both be referenced.

In your case GameController references a player prefab, but the player in the scene is a new object, which was created on scene start by CLONING the player prefab. Since it was created only on scene start - another prefab can never reference it.

To solve this, you can take couple approaches.

**First**, parent both player and game controller under 1 new object, call it GameManager for example. Then you will have only one prefab - game manager, that contains both player and controller.

**Second** option, the one I usually use, is to find the player object at load time. Instead of passing player s a public argument, find it on awake, for example like this:

```
private Player player;
void  Awake() {
    player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
    Assert.IsNotNull(player);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prefabs need to exist (be instantiated) in scenes to function, what you're attempting to do is a workflow of scriptable objects.

Instead of attaching a source prefab from your project directories through the inspector, try looking for an existing instance of the prefab in the scene (at runtime).

```
private void Awake()
{
    player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
}
```